# How to know the installed Ubuntu version is beta2 or final release

Tags: 13.04

For example, I haved install Ubuntu 13.04 beta2 and `sudo apt-get update & upgrade`, and `lsb_release` shows:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.04
Release:        13.04
Codename:       raring
```

But can not find `beta 2` symbol. Does that mean upgraded to final release?

Comment: Amongst I suspect other places, the MOTD shown when you log in via SSH or similar indicates whether you are on the development branch or not. (This is the file `/etc/motd`).

Comment: This information appears to be duplicated in the `/etc/issue`, `/etc/os-release` and `/etc/lsb-release` files, from which presumably the output above comes. These come from the package `base-files`, and the MOTD is generated from this data. If the text `development branch` no longer appears, you have something pretty close to the final version.

Comment: @chronitis I believe your comment would make a good answer too :-))

Answer (score 0):

Try using this command to show full release info:

`cat /etc/*release`